# Check ROS Version in CMake File with Catkin

Tags: ros, catkin, build, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to check the version of ROS being used in the CMakeLists.txt file? i.e., are there any variables or macros to query the version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148831/check-ros-version-in-cmake-file-with-catkin/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2014-04-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question is what you mean with "ROS version".

Each package has its own version number and they level independently. After calling `find_package()` to find a catkin package `foo` you can access the version variables for it (as it is recommended CMake standard):

- ${foo_VERSION}
  * ${roscpp_VERSION_MAJOR}
- ${roscpp_VERSION_MINOR}
  * ${roscpp_VERSION_PATCH}

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-04-07**:
Great, this will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to know the distro (e.g. kinetic, lunar etc.), you can check the `ROS_DISTRO` environment variable, and similar to [this file:](https://github.com/krishauser/Klampt/blob/master/CMakeModules/FindROS.cmake) you can try to look for the ROS header file if the environment variable wasn't set:

```
set(ROS_FOUND FALSE)
if(DEFINED ENV{ROS_DISTRO})
  set(FOUND_ROS_DISTRO $ENV{ROS_DISTRO})
  set(ROS_FOUND TRUE)
else()
  message("ROS distro variable not set. Trying to figure it out...")
  set(AVAILABLE_ROS_VERSIONS "melodic;lunar;kinetic;jade;indigo")
  set(ROS_FOUND FALSE)
  foreach(version ${AVAILABLE_ROS_VERSIONS})
    if(NOT ROS_FOUND)
      find_path(ROS_H ros.h PATHS /opt/ros/${version}/include/ros)
      if(ROS_H)
        message("Found ros version ${version}")
        set(FOUND_ROS_DISTRO ${version})
        set(ROS_FOUND TRUE)
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endif()

if(ROS_FOUND)
  if($ENV{ROS_DISTRO} STREQUAL "melodic")
    message("Using ROS Kinetic")
    # Do stuff specific to Kinetic
  elseif($ENV{ROS_DISTRO} STREQUAL "lunar")
    message("Using ROS Lunar")
    # Do stuff specific to Lunar

  # ... check other versions ...

  else()
    message("Unknown ROS distro:")
    message($ENV{ROS_DISTRO})
  endif()
else()
  message("ROS distro is unknown.")
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) with karma: 642 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2